# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver on netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-12

I am using netbeans 12 with jdk 17.
On building and running the following code, I get this error and no output is shown:

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at bookclass.Bookclass.main(Bookclass.java:114)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I have added all the jar files namely derby.jar, derbyshared.jar, derbyclient.jar, etc.

Code:

```
package bookclass;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

class books {

    void insert() {
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/library");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String s = "insert into bookstb values(" + id + ", '" + t + "', '" + p + "', '" + a + "', " + c + ", " + pr + ")";
            int x = st.executeUpdate(s);
            System.out.println("No. of rows inserted: " + x);
            st.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
public class Bookclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            int ch;
            do {
                System.out.println("1.Insert 2.Update 3.Delete 4.Display 5.Exit\nEnter your choice:");
                ch = in.nextInt();
                books b = new books();
                switch (ch) {
                    case 1:
                        b.insert();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        b.update();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        b.delete();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        b.display();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                }
            } while (ch != 5);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried all the possible solutions available but none solve my issue.

Comment: You miss the jar containing class *org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver* in your class path

Comment: @jens does derbyclient.jar not contain it?

Comment: It should contains the class. But it is in your classpath while running your application

Comment: BTW: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character

Comment: @jens how do I add a class to a jar file?

Comment: How do you run your application?

Comment: @jens I added another jar file containing the class org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver but no changes.

Comment: How have you done it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247746/discussion-between-candy-and-jens).